# Push online repo to bitbucket

Tags: git, macos, svn, github, sourcetree

I'm using sourcetree and want to move my work along with its commit history to another account on source tree so more people can access it. It is a clone of another repo on the target account, but I need to show how it evolved so others can trace bugs.

I googled many different combinations, including this posts' exact title, but couldn't find ANYWHERE that tells you how to do this. All I get is unrelated searches about how to:
create a repo

upload a new repo

upload an existing repo to new repo

clone an existing repo to new repo

but NOT how to:

clone an existing repo TO another  repo

clone an existing repo AS BRANCH OF another  repo

I know this can be done because I've done it before, but that time it was an 8 hour google session and I really don't want to go through that again...

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting bogged down with trying to copy your remote repository because you are insisting that the operation must be a direct copy on the server.  This need not be the case.  As this [blog](http://www.ravisagar.in/blog/duplicating-git-repository-another-repository-bitbucket) discusses, you can achieve what you want by cloning the repository locally, creating a new repository on BitBucket, and then simply pushing your code to this new repository:

```
# change directory to location of copy
mkdir NEW-PROJECT.git
cd NEW-PROJECT.git

# create a local copy of the repository
git clone --bare https://username@bitbucket.org/username/OLD-PROJECT.git

# now create an empty repository on BitBucket called NEW-PROJECT

# push your entire code base to this new repository
git push --mirror https://username@bitbucket.org/username/NEW-PROJECT.git
```